# issues on deploying RESTful webservice on Glassfish server

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, glassfish

I am having some trouble deploying an RESTful application using glassfish 3.1.

The webservice created is using a mysql database and this was quite a hassle to get that running. Now that I don't receive any errors on startup my application wors, sort of.

I can use soapUI to access the wadl file but everytime I want to do a get I get this error in the glassfish logs:

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

I checked and double checked the settings in glassfish and I don't see what the problem is.

I have configured a JDBC resource and JDBC connectionpool.

In the connectionpool I configured the additional properties by filling in the user, password, servername, databasename etc. The ping function also tells me that all is well…

So now I am all blank, I don't understand why this is happening. Are there other places that I need to configure stuff?

[edit]

Ok, i changed the Url property to URL (in stead of Url) and now that seems to work...

Next error is

Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: No PasswordCredential found

[edit 2]

I reloaded the glassfish server and now i am back at the: "Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected" error

What is going on here?

Comment: Alright i fixed the problem.

It seems that the reset button in the admin panel (on port 4848) isnt actualy resetting the server service. 

The stop button DOES stop the service and once you started it from the command line it all should work like a charm.

So this one is for the creators of Glassfish: Please make a reset button that DOES reset the service. That would be awesome :-)